# CGEventTapCreate callback is not running

Tags: macos, core-graphics

I have some C++ code that looks like this:

```
  CFRunLoopRef ref = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
  CGEventMask mask = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDown) |
                     CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseUp) |
                     CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventRightMouseDown) |
                     CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventRightMouseUp) |
                     CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventMouseMoved) |
                     CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDragged) |
                     CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventRightMouseDragged) |
                     CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventScrollWheel);

  CFMachPortRef tap =
      CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap,
                       kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly, mask, OnMouseEvent, this);

  CFRunLoopSourceRef source =
      CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, tap, 0);
  CFRunLoopAddSource(ref, source, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
  CGEventTapEnable(tap, true);

  CFRunLoopRun();

  CGEventTapEnable(tap, false);
  CFRunLoopRemoveSource(ref, source, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
  CFRelease(source);
  CFRelease(tap);
```

`OnMouseEvent` is not being called when I move the mouse around, click, or scroll. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the application that's running this code is added to accessibility in security and privacy. In [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cgr4swwyeay6gc0/Screenshot%202019-11-27%2014.54.47.png?dl=0), iterm is added, and so running this program from iterm will work.

Here's a [github issue](https://github.com/kapetan/osx-mouse/issues/12) that includes code for running sample code you've mentioned, that only works when accessibility is turned on.